# Can i install lubuntu on a netbook only with my usb?

Tags: lubuntu

My netbook's xp os doesn't work so i want to install lubuntu but what i have to do? Download the llubuntus latest version and then my netbook's drivers and that's it? Help

Netbook (Acer a0531h) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [download your preferred version of Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) (I recommend the LTS version) and then [create a boot usb with the downloaded image file](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-lubuntu-on-a-flash-drive-using-windows/).

Once you have created the boot usb insert it into your laptop and boot it up. Different laptops use different keybindings but look for a setting that says something like "select boot device" and press (and hold) the corresponding key during the boot-up process. If you don't see any text like that it will likely be f10, f11, f12 or escape, try each of these.

From there the Lubuntu installer will start and you should be able to follow the on-screen instructions from there.

Comment: Do i have to install any drivers like wlan connection?

Comment: only for propritery hardware. You can chec if everything works ok by boot into 'live mode' ( default option )

Comment: as @totti says, check that your wlan is working in the installation environment. If it's got no problems then you will be fine. If your wireless is not working properly try inserting an ethernet cable and selecting the checkbox that says something like "download updates during installation" and it will try to download your wireless driver automatically.